# YouTube API v3 returns no items

Tags: youtube-data-api

A week ago I started using the YouTube API v3, and have been able to retrieve 13 items from the API using this URL:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={MyKey}&channelId={AChannelId}&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=5
```

Today I used this exact same call/URL and now it returns:

```
// 20140828161458
// https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={MyKey}&channelId={AChannelId}&>part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=5

{
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "\"gLjvtM18QUCicnbwPLo7vn_YIlg/Z7muB3yLsIIdSeQTKlRVObzSk8M\"",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 0,
    "resultsPerPage": 5
  },
  "items": [

  ]
}
```

So no items are being returned, eventhough there should be 13. I used another channelId to make sure the problem wasn't in the channelId, but it also returned nothing.

I have checked the Google blog, but there was no mention of a change. Anyone have an idea what could be wrong?

Comment: OK, more people are having issues:
https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3613&thanks=3613&ts=1409243662