# YouTube API - channelListResponse->items empty

Tags: php, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Since around 17-Dec-2015 11:30:00 UTC, for some Google accounts, the YouTube API is returning an empty `items` sub-array when getting

`$channelsResponse = $youtube->channels->listChannels('status, snippet', array(
      'mine' => 'true',
      'userIp' => $user_ip
 ));`.

Does anyone have any ideas why, or what type of account would produce this type of response?

```
Array
(
[kind] => youtube#channelListResponse
[etag] => "kuL0kDMAqRo3pU7O0pwlO-Lfzp4/tq_PhL9iSiPcDtwajpv63Dy8fEk"
[pageInfo] => Array
    (
        [totalResults] => 0
        [resultsPerPage] => 0
    )

[items] => Array
    (
    )

)
```

I'm not sure if it's related to [youtube api v3 returns no items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25551553/youtube-api-v3-returns-no-items) because the `resultsPerPage` always shows as `0`

Comment: Is it possible that these channels have now closed, or do you know that there should definitely be some data to return?